# Load a PowerShell module for debugging when starting Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac, powershell-v6.0

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac (7.7.2; build 21) to create a PowerShell provider using C#.

I'd like to have the IDE load PowerShell for debugging.

The project's run configuration:

- Start external project:  `/usr/local/bin/pwsh`
- Arguments:  `-NoProfile -NoExit -File "./InstallProvider.ps1"`

`InstallProvider.ps1`:

```
Import-Module "./PsMyModule.psd1" -Force -Verbose
```

`PsMyModule.psd1`:

```
@{
  # Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
  RootModule = 'PsMyModule.dll'
}
```

Both files (`ps1`,`psd1`) are marked `Copy to output`.

When I run the project in debug mode, I get this error:

> The argument './InstallProvider.ps1' is not recognized as the name of
>   a script file. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> Usage: pwsh[.exe] [[-File]  [args]]
>                     [-Command { - |  [-args ]
>                                   |  [] } ]
>                     [-ConfigurationName ] [-EncodedCommand ]
>                     [-ExecutionPolicy ] [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]
>                     [-Interactive] [-NoExit] [-NoLogo] [-NonInteractive] [-NoProfile]
>                     [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}] [-Version] [-WindowStyle ]
>                     [-WorkingDirectory ]
>
> ```
>    pwsh[.exe] -h | -Help | -? | /?
> ```
>
> PowerShell Online Help https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
>
> All parameters are case-insensitive. The application was terminated by
>   an unknown signal: Current platform doesn't support this value.
>   Parameter name: value Actual value was 64.

When I run `pwsh` from the Terminal, however, the module it loaded as expected:

```
~/.../bin/Debug/netstandard2.0$ pwsh -NoExit -File "./InstallProvider.ps1"
PowerShell 6.1.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

VERBOSE: Loading module from path '/Users/[user]/Projects/Visual Studio 2017/PsMyModule/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/PsMyModule.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path '/Users/[user]/Projects/Visual Studio 2017/PsMyModule/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/PsMyModule.dll'.
```

None of these variations work either:

- `-File ".\InstallProvider.ps1"`
- `-File InstallProvider.ps1`
- `-File "./InstallProvider.ps1"`

** edit 0 **

I changed the `File` parameter to `"/Users/[user]/Projects/Visual Studio 2017/PsMyModule/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/InstallProvider.ps1"`

```
PowerShell 6.1.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.

Import-Module : The specified module './PsMyModule.psd1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At /Users/[user]/Projects/Visual Studio 2017/PsMyModule/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/InstallProvider.ps1:1 char:1
+ Import-Module "./PsMyModule.psd1" -Force -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (./PsMyModule.psd1:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

PS />
```

It would seem that relative paths are not being correctly interpreted.  Moreover, the prompt `PS \>` doesn't seem to accept input.

** /edit 0 **

** edit 1 **

I created a similar project in Visual Studio 2017 for Windows.  The debug settings:

[image]

which loaded the module as expected:

```
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\FooModule.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\FooModule.dll'.
PS C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0>
```

** /edit 1 **

What am I missing?  What is different about the OS X version?

Comment: have you tried a full path to the ps1 file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the project target dir as the "**Run in Directory**" as you are not starting a project, the working environment will be based upon VS4M's environment, and the shell is not in the project debug/release directory output:

[image]

Comment: This works, but the prompt (`PS \>`) doesn't seem to accept input.

Comment: I have `run on external console` and `pause console output` checked in Run | Configuration | Default.  Should this open a new Terminal window, then start `pwsh`?